# MySQL randomly says SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection Refused

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, connection

Using PHP, Symfony Framework, MySQL.

Switched to new server.

System randomly triggers `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused`. Does this related to server/database setting?

Database setting adjusted:

```
max_allowed_packet: 268435456
```

Comment: what do the logs say?

Comment: @Kvin Chan  please post last 100 lines of your error log.  Please also post results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%connect%'; and B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE '%connect%'; .